# After login the query immediately run and tries get data from database

Tags: apex

After login the query immediately run and tries get data from database in my apex app.I want the page get data after user enter the parameters in page. I want the apex page to not run query immediately after login. thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Is this question related to oracle application express rather than force.com apex?

Answer (score 0):

go to the page in question, I assume this will be the home page or page 1 in your application.
go to the region definition.
find conditions tab and put a condition in there.

Make it dependant on a value of an item possibly.

i.e.
lets say you had a page item called P1_USERNAME and you wanted only to show this region when the USERNAME was scurtis

on the conditions tab:

**Condition Type:**

Value of item / column in Expression 1 = Expression 2

**Expression 1**
P1_USERNAME

**Expression 2**
scurtis